# Why is my check box button non responsive in shinny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I have this shiny app which includes a checkbox button:

```
library(bold)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

grades2<-function(groups,inputz,coordz){
  taxon<-bold_seqspec(taxon=groups, format = "tsv")
  taxon2<-taxon[taxon$species_name!=""|is.na(taxon$species_name),]
  taxon2<-taxon2[!(taxon2$bin_uri == "" | is.na(taxon2$bin_uri)), ]
  taxon2$base_number=str_count(taxon2$nucleotides, pattern="[A-Z]")
  taxon2<-taxon2[taxon2$base_number>=inputz,]
  if (coordz==TRUE){
    taxon2<-taxon2[!(is.na(taxon2$lat)) | taxon2$country!="",]
  }else{
    taxon2<-taxon2
  }
  assign('taxon2',taxon2,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}


ui <- navbarPage(title=tags$h3("APP"),tabPanel(column(12,align="center",tags$h4("Download"),tags$br(),
                                                      sliderInput("seqsize", "Mininum number of base pairs for sequences in reference library:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),textOutput("SliderText"),
                                                      checkboxInput("rmvpaises", "Remove records without data on country of origin or latitude", TRUE),
                                 textInputAddon(inputId="taxa2",addon=icon("search"),width="500px",label=tags$h5(tags$strong("Enter the name of the taxonomic group or groups separated by commas, without spaces:")),placeholder="Example: Carnivora,Ursidae,Artiodactyla,Soricomorpha"),
                                 downloadButton("downloadData_2","Download"))))

server <- function(input, output){
  #sliderValues <- reactive({as.integer(input$seqsize)})
  #output$values <- renderText({
  #  sliderValues()
  #})
  taxaInput_2 <- reactive({grades2(unlist(strsplit(input$taxa2, ",")),as.integer(input$seqsize),input$rmvpaises)})
  output$downloadData_2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$taxa2,sep_out=",", ".tsv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      shiny::withProgress(
        value=10,
        {
          shiny::incProgress(10/10)
          write_tsv(taxaInput_2(), file)
        }
      )
    }
  )
  output$value <- renderText({ input$rmvpaises })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

For some reason while using the app, the check box is non-responsive. It doesn't change.
The input of the check box is being used in the initial function "grades2" and it is the "coordz" argument.
Thank you so much for any answer

Comment: I've seen this a lot more recently. When an `if` conditional is supposed to be a logical, why do you use `if (cond == TRUE)` instead of just `if (cond)`? (Similarly, I've been seeing `if (cond == FALSE)` ... why not just `if (! cond)`?) Is there a tutorial or class that is encouraging this method?

Comment: I've tried it but the button is still non-responsive I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the non-optional argument `title` for `tabPanel`. Consequently, it's using the `column` UI element as the title for the tab which I'm assuming is doing weird stuff with the z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You need an observer to update the checkboxInput on the server side.  The checkbox works fine in this code

```
grades2<-function(groups,inputz,coordz){
  taxon<-bold_seqspec(taxon=groups, format = "tsv")
  taxon2<-taxon[taxon$species_name!=""|is.na(taxon$species_name),]
  taxon2<-taxon2[!(taxon2$bin_uri == "" | is.na(taxon2$bin_uri)), ]
  taxon2$base_number=str_count(taxon2$nucleotides, pattern="[A-Z]")
  taxon2<-taxon2[taxon2$base_number>=inputz,]
  if (coordz) {
    taxon2<-taxon2[!(is.na(taxon2$lat)) | taxon2$country!="",]
  }else{
    taxon2<-taxon2
  }
  assign('taxon2',taxon2,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

ui <- navbarPage(title=tags$h3("APP"),tabPanel(value="Panel1" , column(12,align="center",tags$h4("Download"),tags$br(),
                                                      sliderInput("seqsize", "Mininum number of base pairs for sequences in reference library:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),textOutput("SliderText"),
                                                      checkboxInput("rmvpaises", "Remove records without data on country of origin or latitude", TRUE),
                                                      textInputAddon(inputId="taxa2",addon=icon("search"),width="500px",label=tags$h5(tags$strong("Enter the name of the taxonomic group or groups separated by commas, without spaces:")),placeholder="Example: Carnivora,Ursidae,Artiodactyla,Soricomorpha"),
                                                      downloadButton("downloadData_2","Download"))))



server <- function(input, output, session){
  #sliderValues <- reactive({as.integer(input$seqsize)})
  #output$values <- renderText({
  #  sliderValues()
  #})
 
  observe({
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "rmvpaises", value=input$rmvpaises)
  })
  
  taxaInput_2 <- reactive({grades2(unlist(strsplit(input$taxa2, ",")),as.integer(input$seqsize),input$rmvpaises)})
  output$downloadData_2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$taxa2,sep_out=",", ".tsv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      shiny::withProgress(
        value=10,
        {
          shiny::incProgress(10/10)
          write_tsv(taxaInput_2(), file)
        }
      )
    }
  )
  output$value <- renderText({ input$rmvpaises })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```